# how to create and send the request/response body for the post method in test class

Tags: apex, rest

```
static testMethod void testPost(){

    RestRequest req = new RestRequest(); 
    RestResponse res = new RestResponse();
    Profile testEditorProfile = [Select id from Profile where Name= :System.Label.Profile_Editor];

    req.requestURI = System.URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl()+'...XYZ...';  
    req.httpMethod = 'PUT';

    TService.PostResponseWrapper postResponseInstance=TService.doPost();

    system.debug('***Response***'+postResponseInstance);
}
```

Note:The post  method is defined in the service class and  does not have any 
     arguments

Answer (score 0):

You can use RestContext to set request and response ,
Use addHeader(name, value), addParameter(name, value) to set header and params of method.

```
   RestRequest req = new RestRequest(); 
   RestResponse res = new RestResponse();

    req.requestURI = '';  //Request URL
    req.httpMethod = '';//HTTP Request Type
    req.requestBody = Blob.valueof(JsonMsg);
    RestContext.request = req;
    RestContext.response= res;
    YourClass.testPost();
    Test.stopTest();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create one common mock class and method which will help in testing all callouts:

//=== Main Class ===

```
 global class MockHttpResponseHandler implements HttpCalloutMock {
 private Map<String,ResponseEndpointHolder> responseMap = new 
 Map<String,ResponseEndpointHolder>();

//This causes the ? query params to be ignored when routing responses
public Boolean ignoreQuery {get; set;}

public MockHttpResponseHandler(){
    ignoreQuery = true;
}

public void addResponse(String endpoint, IMockResponse response){
    if(ignoreQuery){
        endpoint = getBaseUrl(endpoint);
    }

    ResponseEndpointHolder holder;
    if(responseMap.containsKey(endpoint)){
        holder = responseMap.get(endpoint);
    }else{
        holder = new ResponseEndpointHolder();
        responseMap.put(endpoint, holder);
    }
    holder.addMockResponse(response);
}

global HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {
    String endpoint = req.getEndpoint();
    if(ignoreQuery){
        endpoint = getBaseUrl(endpoint);
    }
    if(!responseMap.containsKey(endpoint)){
        throw new MockHttpHandlerException('No response for endpoint:' + endpoint);
    }
    ResponseEndpointHolder responseHolder = responseMap.get(endpoint);
    return responseHolder.getMockResponse(req);
}

private String getBaseUrl(String endpoint){
    Url baseUrl = new URL(endpoint);
    return baseUrl.getHost() + baseUrl.getPath();
}
```

//=== INNER CLASSES ===

```
//Interface used for MockReponses.
//  Implement this if you need a specialized Mock Response
public interface IMockResponse{
    HTTPResponse getResponse(HTTPRequest req);
    String getMethod();
}

//Base class that covers most simple use cases
public virtual class SimpleMockResponse implements IMockResponse{
    private String method;
    public String getMethod(){
        return method;
    }

    public void setMethod(String value){
        this.method = value;
    }

    public String contentType { get; set;}

    public Integer statusCode {get; set;}

    public Map<String, String> headers {get; set;}

    public String body {get; set;}

    public SimpleMockResponse(String method, String body){
        this.method = method;
        this.body = body;

        this.headers = new Map<String, String>();

        //defaults
        this.statusCode = 200;
        this.contentType = 'application/json';
    }

    public HTTPResponse getResponse(HTTPRequest req) {
        // Create a fake response
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', contentType);
        if(this.body != null){
            res.setBody(body);
        }
        res.setStatusCode(statusCode);
        for(String key : headers.keySet()){
            res.setHeader(key, headers.get(key));
        }

        return res;
    }
}


//Endpoint Handler is used to store a list of reponses for each HTTP method on an endpoint
private class ResponseEndpointHolder{
    protected Map<String, List<IMockResponse>> endpointMethodMap = new Map<String, List<IMockResponse>>();

    public HTTPResponse getMockResponse(HTTPRequest req){
        String method = req.getMethod();
        List<IMockResponse> responses = endpointMethodMap.get(method);
        if(responses == null || responses.size() == 0){
            throw new MockHttpHandlerException('No response for method:' + method);
        }else if(responses.size() == 1){
            return responses[0].getResponse(req);
        }else{
            return responses.remove(0).getResponse(req);
        }
    }

    public void addMockResponse(IMockResponse response){
        String method = response.getMethod();
        if(method == null){
            throw new MockHttpHandlerException('Method cannot be null!');
        }

        if(endpointMethodMap.containsKey(method)){
            endpointMethodMap.get(method).add(response);
        }else{
            endpointMethodMap.put(method, new List<IMockResponse>{ response });
        }
    }
}

public class MockHttpHandlerException extends Exception {}
```

//=== TESTS ===

```
@isTest static void testHttpMockHandler() {
    String url1 = 'http://test.com';
    String url2 = 'http://test2.com';

    MockHttpResponseHandler mock = new MockHttpResponseHandler();

    //going to run this one twice...
    MockHttpResponseHandler.SimpleMockResponse m1 =
            new MockHttpResponseHandler.SimpleMockResponse('GET', 'get1');
    MockHttpResponseHandler.SimpleMockResponse m2 =
            new MockHttpResponseHandler.SimpleMockResponse('GET', 'get2');
    MockHttpResponseHandler.SimpleMockResponse m3 =
            new MockHttpResponseHandler.SimpleMockResponse('POST', 'post1');

    //test multiple items on single method
    mock.addResponse(url1, m1);
    mock.addResponse(url1, m1);
    mock.addResponse(url1, m2);
    //test multiple methods
    mock.addResponse(url1, m3);
    //test for multiple endpoints
    mock.addResponse(url2, m1);


    Test.startTest();
    Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, mock);

    //assert on GETS
    //  get1 should show up twice, then get 2 should show on every additional call
    System.assertEquals('get1', sendRequest('GET', url1));
    //test that Query String is ignored
    System.assertEquals('get1', sendRequest('GET', url1 + '?foo=bar'));
    System.assertEquals('get2', sendRequest('GET', url1));
    System.assertEquals('get2', sendRequest('GET', url1));
    //assert on post
    System.assertEquals('post1', sendRequest('POST', url1));
    //assert on second endpoint
    System.assertEquals('get1', sendRequest('GET', url2));
    Test.stopTest();

}

private static String sendRequest(String method, String endpoint){
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint(endpoint);
    req.setMethod(method);
    Http http = new Http();
    HttpResponse response = http.send(req);
    return response.getBody();
}
```

}

Use this class methods in your test class as below:

```
    @isTest static void testCallout(){
    String getTokenReqResponse = GT_cls_TestDataFactory.getTokenMockResponse();

    MockHttpResponseHandler mock = new MockHttpResponseHandler();
    MockHttpResponseHandler.SimpleMockResponse nameRequest = new 
    MockHttpResponseHandler.SimpleMockResponse('POST', getTokenReqResponse);
    String endpoint ='xxxxxxxxxx';
    mock.addResponse(endpoint, nameRequest);

    Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, mock);
    setUpData();

    Test.startTest();
    //Your main class
    Test.stopTest();
}
```